# How to call AJAX API function from Windows App?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Some company is providing me with web-based API for using their services. I have no problem calling this API functions from within web brower:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://someaddress.com?&key=somekey"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var object = new SomeObject();
object.SomeFunction();
</script>
</head>
```

I am interested in return value of SomeFunction(). 
How would I get this return value from windows application?

Comment: Since when have web-based APIs been called "AJAX APIs"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  That will let you watch the actual HTTP requests, and step through the JavaScript.  In combination, that will let you see where the return value comes from.

Once you understand this, you can replicate the requests (and possibly parts of the JavaScript logic) in your Windows app using an appropriate HTTP client library.

Note that this may be a violation of the TOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed web browser control in WinForm and return value from SomeFunction 
into some DOM element, then you can access that element from WinForm.WebBrowser1.

There are also javascript emulators available, I think you can even use JSCRIPT dll from c#
but that may not work if SomeFunction() depends on DOM.